# Updated NPM but still showing as old version

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Getting "npm: command not found" on this computer. Only way I knew to get it was by uninstalling node with Homebrew and reinstalling from the node.js site. Just reinstalled node.js on this computer and have npm version 2.5.1 with it.
I went to update to the newest (2.7.1) using:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

Updated without any errors, but running `npm -v` tells me I'm still on version 2.5.1

In the process of looking into the issue, see that old npm related files are on this computer. Old Changelog last modified 30 days ago exists saying "v2.7.1 (2015-03-05)" so npm was updated and on here at one point.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you exited that shell session and tried it in a new one?

Comment: Yes, @theWanderer4865, have done so

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034921/how-do-i-install-node-and-npm-so-i-dont-have-to-use-sudo There could be a problem with your set-up because you shouldn't have to use sudo

Comment: Used sudo as per npm's instructions on updating. As far as I can tell permissions seem to be fine. Just browsing through finder to see that npm related files have been modified as of today.

Comment: This computer does show old npm files from 30 days ago with a Read Me showing the most updated npm version in it. I went through uninstalling and reinstalling node because I was receiving "npm: command not found" previously. My only game plan to get npm on here was to reinstall node. Not sure if that was the best way. @theWanderer4865

Comment: I'm on Mavericks @theWanderer4865

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here: there isn't anything really wrong, there just might be some installation issues. Homebrew should be just fine for installing node, Thoughtbot uses it to set-up laptops (see [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop)).

To make sure Node/NPM installation is done in a smooth way, I did this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Per [this](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm) post.

I am on Yosemite and I haven't had any issues using this set-up, especially when updating NPM (did it when I read your question).

Comment: Oh god no! Please don't suggest something like that! There must be a better way than for a specific user to take over a system directory like that.

Comment: I don't find your comment constructive. The converse to this would be allowing NPM packages to have superuser privileges when installing which is arguably way worse. Instead of criticizing an answer in the comments, write one yourself.